# Job description being escaped twice in SO Careers' email

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, email, encoding

I recently subscribed to a mailing list for the SO Careers and notice that the jobs' description are HTML-escaped twice.

For instance this job http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/54725/python-web-developer-remote-possible-rice-university-openstax

### Expected

Its description normally starts with:

```
Rice University’s OpenStax Tutor initiative is searching for a well-qualified Python developer to join a team of
```

### What I got

And here is the output in the mail I received:

```
Rice University&rsquo;s OpenStax Tutor initiative is searching for a well-qualified Python…
```

### Actual HTML behind it

```
Rice University&amp;rsquo;s OpenStax Tutor initiative is searching for a well-qualified Python…
```

Very probably caused by a double HTML-escaping resulting in us being able to see the escaped characters.

**Linked question:** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252665/1524913 (same question that got closed but not migrated - *I don't know why*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Now the unicode character `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2019)` will be displayed in all its curly glory in your scheduled emails, just like its old fashioned friend, the humble but oh-so-straight apostrophe.